# Replace substring from string

Tags: android, string

I have a String `userId:344556\\ncustomerId:233` .

I want to replace the substring `\\n` with new line. So i tried

```
String more = strmoreInfo.replace("\\n", "\n");
```

My desired output is:

```
userId:344556
customerId:233
```

But my current output is:

```
userId:344556\
customerId:233
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'\' is an escape character. You'll want to change the statement to:

```
String more = strmoreInfo.replace("\\\\n", "\n");
```

Comment: Thanks @Tah :) I missed that

Answer (score 0):

I will try your code but i could not found any problem its works......

```
public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {    
    String strmoreInfo="userId:344556\\ncustomerId:233";
    String more = strmoreInfo.replace("\\n", "\n");
     System.out.println(more);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put a space e.g "< SPACE >\n" in second argument of replace method.

```
String more = strmoreInfo.replace("\\n", " \n");
```